# Is possible to use return statement inside expressions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn how can i return in expressions, it might be impossible but any close solution can be helpfull

```
var something = ()=>{
    (true) && (return true)
}

console.log(something())
```

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve by this way ?

Comment: Can you provide an example that's a bit closer to what you'd really want to do? Because here you can simply `return true`...

Comment: No, it's not possible to use the return (or any other) statement in an expression.

Comment: @georg It is a function

Comment: @mplungjan `return` is a  statement, not a function. `a && b` is an expression

Comment: @dee-see bro mine is an simply example i want to know can i use return inside an expression

Comment: what would you like to return if not `true`?

Comment: @VLAZ but i can use the expressions like this (true) ? (variable = true) : (variable = false)

Comment: there is no statement in that conditional operator.

Comment: @VLAZ ()=>{} is a function and can have return true

Comment: @mplungjan yes, that's a function but OP specifically wants to put the `return` statement inside *an expression*. `a && b` is an expression so you cannot have `return` embedded in it. The same way you cannot have it in an arithmetic expression `1 + return 1` or  any other place that takes an expression passing in an argument `alert( return 2 )`, spread syntax, `[...return 3]`, conditional operator `myVar ? return 4 : return 5`, comma operator, `(myVar, return 7)`, an object literal `obj = {key: return 8 }`, variable assignment `myVar = return 9` and so on and so forth.

Comment: @VLAZ judging from the accepted answer I’m not sure OP grasped his own question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and is a logical operator , it checks the logic and return the bool
>   value .you cannot use return statement within logical operator.In that
>   place (just to look cool) you can use ternary operator 
>       for example:

```js
var something = ()=>{
    num=4;
    return (num === 4) ?  "Correct!": "Incorrect!";
    }

console.log(something())
```

Comment: i was already solved myself 

var something = ()=>{
 var val
    (true) && (val = true)
 return val
}

console.log(something())

but yours is more easier and praticle so you won

Comment: OR `var num=4; var something = () => num === 4 ?  "Correct!": "Incorrect!";
 console.log(something())`

Answer (score 1):

Just take an [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) along with the wanted [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

```
if (true) return true;
```

Comment: i know i can use if statement but using expressions is a bit more cool so i want to know can i do it with return

Comment: if that condition acts as early return, you need an `if` statement, despite of beeing *uncool*.

Comment: your answer is true, i `must` use  if, else if my condition acts as early return